# Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, kie, drools-kie-server

This is my configuration :

```
File dtFile = new File("path");
       
        if (dtFile != null) {
            KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(
                    kieServices.getResources().newFileSystemResource(dtFile).setResourceType(ResourceType.DTABLE)
            );
            KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
            kieBuilder.buildAll();
            KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
            kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
        }
```

and there is this error (Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0)
at `kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());`
...

> **The weird thing is if i open the excel file and save it manually (ctrl +s) the process will work successfully without errors**

Comment: Did you save `dtFile` to your filesystem and verify it's actually saved before entering this 'if' statement? (save/write being async operations.)

Answer (score 0):

We see this issue when the DRL file not configured properly.
This error is misleading, please make sure drl file is not corrupted.